# How to handle errors for inline functions inside an object

Tags: javascript, object, testing, error-handling, inline

At the moment I've got this:

```
const checkText = (t) => ({
    isNotEmpty: function () {
      if (t.length === 0) {
        throw new Error("isNotEmpty false");
      }
      return this;
    },
    isEmail: function () {
      const emailRegex = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{1,20})+$/;
      if (!emailRegex.test(t)) {
        throw new Error("isEmail false");
      }
      return this;
    }
};
```

Using a try catch, if the text is not valid, an error is thrown and handled this way:

```
const isFieldValid = (email) => {
  try {
    const v = checkText(email)
      .isNotEmpty()
      .isEmail();
    if (v) {
      return true;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
};
```

The goal is to short and clean the code, to avoiding the try catch, to have the final call in one line like this:

```
const isFieldValid = checkText('valid text').isNotEmpty().isEmail(); // one line
```

PS: I know there are library out there for validation. The code is an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
class CheckText {
  constructor(t) {
    this.t = t;
    this.valid = true;
  }
  isNotEmpty() {
    this.valid &&= this.t.length>0;
    return this;
  }
  isEmail() {
    this.valid &&= CheckText.emailRegex.test(this.t);
    return this;
  }
  static emailRegex = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{1,20})+$/;
}

const isFieldValid = new CheckText('test@example.com').isNotEmpty().isEmail().valid;
console.log(isFieldValid);
```

However, I'd prefer to do it like this:

```js
const emailRegex = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{1,20})+$/;
const isNotEmpty = t => t.length>0;
const isEmail = t => emailRegex.test(t);
const validate = (t, validators) => validators.every(v=>v(t));
console.log(validate('test@example.com', [isNotEmpty, isEmail]));
console.log(validate('testexample.com',  [isNotEmpty, isEmail]));
console.log(validate('',                 [isNotEmpty, isEmail]));
```

Comment: Thank you Andrew for both your implementation. 

About the first one: the trick was using the logical and assignment operator `&&=` and adding the `valid` property. I like it because it's possible to use it keeping the Object structure. 

About the second. Yes, I love it. Using `every`, it's very neat. I'll definitely use it in future.

Thank you for sharing and your time 